# Why my rendered DataTable is interrupted by the invalidateLater?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to the shiny and I meet a lot of problems.  I have a function that can identify every row of the given DataFrame A and pick out **needed rows** by *index and iteration*. And then add the picked rows to a new DataFrame B.

What I want is to exhibit the DataFrame B dynamically every iteration.I've tried **for loop**,but it didn't work. By searching,I found the **invalidateLater** can replace the **for loop**. But new problem occurs——my rendered DataTable was just destroyed during the iteration. I've tried many approaches,like set priority to the renderOutput function and use ***future*** package to run the function in another session.Increasing the time of the **invalidateLater** is dismissed because the iterations is quite big.

But all of these didn't work. I'm gonna crazy because this,is there any shiny guru can help me?

Here are the reproducible codes.

`code:`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("dt"),
    actionButton("btn","erar"),
    verbatimTextOutput("test")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    dt_test <- reactiveVal(data.frame())
    active <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
    observe({output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        dt_test()
    }, options = list(processing = FALSE))},priority = 9)
    textvals <- reactiveVal(1)
    observe({output$test <- renderText(textvals())},priority = 1)
    observeEvent(input$btn,{active(TRUE)})
    observe({
        if (active()){
            invalidateLater(1000)
            isolate({
                textvals(textvals() + 1)
                arow = data.frame(1,1:3)
                Sys.sleep(5)
                dt_test(rbind(dt_test(),arow))
                if (textvals()>15){
                    active(FALSE)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}




shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It is better to use `reactiveValues` object for `dt_test`.  Also, if `dt_test` is your dataframe A, where is your dataframe B?

Comment: @YBS : Actually....`dt_test` is my dataframe B, to simplify the code, I use adding a row instead of picking row.

Comment: You are adding 3 rows in each iteration and stops after 15 as shown in the code.  I am not sure what the problem is here, as your dataframe B is displayed after each iteration (adding 3 rows in each iteration).

Comment: @YBS Sorry,I update the codes.Please run the current codes and you will notice that the dataTable wasn't showed until the iteration ended.

Comment: @YBS May be I have to set random number of `Sys.Sleep()` because running time of my function is not fixed.So you can observe that the rendered DataTable was destroyed.